# How can I add FlowLayoutPanel and PictureBox in TabPage?

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net, flowlayoutpanel

How do I add flowlayout panel and picturebox to tab page?
I want to add all image urls to picturebox and picturebox list added to flow layout and also added to tabpage:

[image]

This my code

```
List<FlowLayoutPanel> flows = new List<FlowLayoutPanel>();
FlowLayoutPanel flow = new FlowLayoutPanel();
List<TabPage> tp = new List<TabPage>();
foreach (var item in edu.data)
{
    flow.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    flow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    flow.Tag = item.content;
    flow.AutoScroll = true;
    flow.Name = item.category;
    foreach (var item2 in item.content)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Size = new Size(170, 130);
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pb.LoadAsync("https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/" + item2.urlYutub.Split('=')[1] + "/hqdefault.jpg");
        flow.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
    flows.Add(flow);
}
foreach (var flo in flows)
{
    TabPage tp2 = new TabPage();
    tp2.Text = flo.Name;
    tp2.Controls.Add(flo);
    tp.Add(tp2);
}
for (int index = 0; index < tp.Count; index++)
{
    tabEducation.TabPages.Add(tp[index]);
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:json.net]?  I don't see any JSON in your question.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (var item in edu.data)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel flow = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    flow.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    flow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    flow.Tag = item.content;
    flow.AutoScroll = true;
    flow.Name = item.category;
    foreach (var item2 in item.content)
    {
        if (item.category == flow.Name)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Size = new Size(170, 130);
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pb.LoadAsync("https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/" + item2.urlYutub.Split('=')[1] + "/hqdefault.jpg");
            flow.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
    }
    TabPage tp = new TabPage();
    tp.Text = flow.Name;
    tp.Controls.Add(flow);
    tabEducation.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```